# child process should start after it meets the condition in Python

Tags: python

```
import os
import pdb

def timeConsumingFunction():
    x=1

    for n in xrange(100000000):
        x+=1
        print "child runnig",x
    return x

x=1
child=-1
for n in xrange(100000):
    x+=1
    print "parent running",x
    if x>50000:
        pid=os.fork()
        if pid>0:
            child=pid

        else:
            print timeConsumingFunction()
            os._exit(0)
os.waitpid(child,0)
print "hello"
```

I want to print the parent first from 0 to 50000 and when it reaches 50000 it has to start a new child process and from then parent and child should continue executing in parallel. But in this code after reaching 50000 it stops executing "parallel running " statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will spawn many, *many* (theoretically up to 50000) children, not just one. The parent probably keeps running a bit when the OS lets it, but you may not be able to see its output under the storm of output from the numerous children it kicks off.

Try changing the `x > 50000` condition to `x == 50000` and I suspect it will work as you intend, with exactly one child running beside the parent.